# PySpark -Streaming job stuck and not processing further

Tags: python, scala, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-kafka

I have a PySpark Streaming job(Spark version 2.4.5) runs on kubernetes with a driver and 4 executors.The purpose of the job is to consume data from a Kafka topic and process them and load the final data to ElasticSearch.

### Problem:

At times, we face issue with Kafka cluster. And, thus the PySpark Streaming job won't get any data to process/consume and that is acceptable.However,
even after when the Kafka cluster becomes OK, the PySpark Streaming job will not consume/process any further records from the Kafka topic.The job will wait indefinetely

Error: No error found on driver or any of the executors.

### tail Log of one of the executors:

```
> 21/11/24 16:46:32 INFO ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator: Getting 1
> non-empty blocks including 1 local blocks and 0 remote blocks 21/11/24
> 16:46:32 INFO ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator: Started 0 remote fetches in
> 0 ms 21/11/24 16:46:32 INFO CodeGenerator: Code generated in 12.569815
> ms 21/11/24 16:46:32 INFO CodeGenerator: Code generated in 4.696542 ms
> 21/11/24 16:46:32 INFO EsDataFrameWriter: Writing to [list_anom]
> 21/11/24 16:46:33 INFO Executor: Finished task 3.0 in stage 299400.0
> (TID 438086). 9114 bytes result sent to driver 21/11/24 16:46:33 INFO
> BlockManager: Removing RDD 777788 21/11/24 16:46:33 INFO BlockManager:
> Removing RDD 777807 21/11/24 16:46:33 INFO BlockManager: Removing RDD
> 777951 21/11/24 16:46:33 INFO BlockManager: Removing RDD 778649
> 21/11/24 17:01:42 INFO BlockManager: Removing RDD 776873 21/11/24
> 17:01:42 INFO BlockManager: Removing RDD 777013
```

### snippet of PySpark which streams kafka data:

```
inputDF = spark \
                .readStream \
                .format("kafka") \
                .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", Kakfa_broker_ip:port) \
                .option("subscribe", "kafka_topic") \
                .load() \
                .selectExpr("CAST(value AS STRING)") \
                .writeStream \
                .trigger(processingTime='30 seconds') \
                .option("checkpointLocation", "/file-storage/Checkpoints")\
                .foreachBatch(processKafkaInput) \
                .outputMode("append") \
                .start()

inputDF.awaitTermination()
```

### Some info from UI:

[image]

### Thread Dump of driver:

[image]

Comment: recently, seems i faced the same behavior, i use spark 2.3.1 and application code by scala.,before it get pending, i got a `org.apache.kafka.common.errors.DisconnectionException`. could you share if you have anything update.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% on this but you may need some error handling in your  PySpark Streaming job to call `streamingContext.stop()` if garbage data causes an error.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Can I try the below ? I assume the program will wait for 1000 seconds and if there is no data to consume, it will terminate.
.
streamingContext.awaitTerminationOrTimeout(1000)
streamingContext.stop()

Comment: It's hard to know without more information about which file is calling which and what's where. But if you have a timeout I imagine it wouldn't get hung on broken input...